# insert multiple shopping cart into database

Tags: php

I already search more about this topic solution "How to insert multiple item into database", but i can't understand. Hope somebody can help me !

```
shopping cart 

    {
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)){

                $total=($row['product_price']*$row['quantity']);
                $tot = $tot + ($row['product_price']*$row['quantity']);
            ?>
      <tr>
        <td align="center"><img src="<?php echo $item['product_image'];?>" width="150px" height="150px" alt=""/></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['product_name'];?></td>
        <td><?php echo $row['quantity'];?></td>
        <td>RM <?php echo $total;?></td>
        <td style="text-align:center"><a href="delete_shopping_cart_item.php?id=<?php echo $row["id"];?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?');">
        Remove
        </a></td>
      </tr>
    <?php
    }       

if(isset($_POST['submit1']))
{
    $customer = $_SESSION['login_user'];
    $res = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT * FROM shopping_cart where customer ='$customer'");
    $row=mysqli_fetch_array($res);

        $qty = $row['quantity'];
        $product_name = $row['product_name'];
        $rname = $_POST['rname'];
        $raddress = $_POST['raddress'];
        $rcontactno = $_POST['rcontactno'];
        $total = $_SESSION['total'] ;

        mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into confirm_order (product_name,quantity,total_price,receiver_name,receiver_address,receiver_contact,customer)
        values('$product_name','$qty','$total','$rname','$raddress','$rcontactno','$customer')");

        $_SESSION['receiver'] = $rname;
    }
}
```

Comment: what you want now?

Comment: you can use array

Comment: i want to insert multiple value into database

Comment: i am newbie in development, so if use array how to use it

Comment: send me friend request at facebook/mr.jarves. Then give your team viewer details

Comment: Are you getting any errors.  If so what are they?

Comment: M R Jarvis is your facebook name?

Comment: no errors. i just want to insert multiple value into database

Comment: Do you mean insert multiple rows?

Comment: I searched more in this topic, more people said to use a foreach loop, but I don't know how to use in this code

Comment: Example : in my shopping cart have 2 item then i click checkout them would inset to my database

Comment: Updated my answer below

Comment: @newbie yes. send it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($res)) {

 $qty = $row['quantity'];
 $product_name = $row['product_name'];
 $rname = $_POST['rname'];
 $raddress = $_POST['raddress'];
 $rcontactno = $_POST['rcontactno'];
 $total = $_SESSION['total'] ;

mysqli_query($mysqli,"insert into confirm_order (product_name,quantity,total_price,receiver_name,receiver_address,receiver_contact,customer)
values('$product_name','$qty','$total','$rname','$raddress','$rcontactno','$customer')");

}
```

Comment: thank Joseph_J answer my question to solve my question.